# Error 415 when trying to send object + file as multipart request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I know that sending multipart requests together with JSON object already had many threads but unfortunately none of them actually resolved the problem for me.

I created controller accepting object containing IFormFile together with some metadata object:

```
public class DocumentMultipartRequest
{
    [FromForm]
    public DocumentMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
    [FromForm]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

The controller looks like that:

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<Guid> AddDocument(DocumentMultipartRequest request)
{

}
```

Apparently Swagger understands my intention correctly because I have string($binary) allowing me to choose a file and object with proper fields inside to fill, unfortunately when I set everything and press "Execute" I will receive "415 Unsupported Media Type" error as result.

How can I fix this problem while maintaining Swagger still understanding my intention, so API is nicely documented?

Setting multiple [Consumes] types didn't help, marking whole DocumentMultipartRequest  as [FromForm] will divide DocumentMetadata into different fields f.e. DocumentMetadata.Property1, DocumentMetadata.Property2. The latter will actually work fine and will be properly bound to DocumentMetadata object on backend side, but if possible I would rather accept normal JSON because metadata object may get complicated later on.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Kestrel (for development), IIS, Apache? I know that for Apache you need to set `FILE_UPLOADS=ON`. It's just a hutch however...

Comment: Kestrel will most probably be used in production environment later on.